# How to handle PDF pagination in PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to create PDFs from html.

It works fine, but I can't find out how to work with pagination; I want to create a page for each div in my document, but I can't find anything in the doc. about pagination.

If my document is short, it makes only one page, and if it is bigger, it creates one second empty page and my contents are in the first page which becomes very long.

Any idea ? (I am using phantomJS-node module for nodeJS)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

PhantomJS takes care of webkit’s css implementation. To implement manual page breaks you can use these properties :

- `page-break-before` : auto/always/avoid/...
- `page-break-inside` : auto/always/avoid/...
- `page-break-after` : auto/always/avoid/...

For example, a div can be :

```
 <div style="page-break-before:always;"><!-- content --></div>
```

or

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;"> <!-- content --></div>
```

Controlling page breaks when printing in Webkit is sometimes not easy, in particular with long html tables.

Comment: Divided my pages in divs, applying page-break-after on each one of them, apart from the last one. Works like a charm

Comment: i also facing the same problem but when add page-break-after on every page it is creating alot of spaces,can you help me?

Comment: PhantomJS currently does not support "page-break-inside: avoid;"

Comment: According to the issue in github, it's fixed in source but not in the downloadable builds:

"Just built from source and its fixed :)"

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10638#issuecomment-42676356

Comment: For those unable to build from source try the CSS Hack: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10638#issuecomment-20186253

Answer (score 4):

Very late, but I had issues with "break-inside:avoid" using JsReport that were fixed by changing the element's display type to inline-block.  More info here:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10638

Answer (score 4):

You should see this [issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10638) with different tips.

Try to use `display:inline-block` in the element that you don't want to breaks because the page break. The reasoning behind is that webkit already tries to preserve images from breaking. And images are inline-blocks.

Comment: This worked for me, changing it to display: table; allowed the element to page break.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination works fine with :

```
 var page = webPage.create();

 page.paperSize = {
  format: 'A4',
  orientation: 'portrait',
  margin: '1cm'
 }
```

Check documentation here http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/paper-size.html