# Export Multiple Highcharts to Multi-page PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, highcharts, export-to-pdf

I am trying to export multiple charts to a pdf file, with each of the charts to be displayed on a different pdf page.

`Code here:` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd7bB/2264/)

You can see multiple chart are exported, but they are all placed on a single pdf page. Does anyone know of a way to separate, so that each chart is placed on to its own page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how to do what you want with the Highcharts PDF server, you can do this with the http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf server by formatting a div containing the charts and surrounding charts with a div setting the page-break.

See http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6eb7e/23/

```
<div id="JSFiddle">
    <!-- Insert your document here -->
    <header style="display:none;margin-top:20px;"><p>Add your header</p></header>     
    <footer style="display:none"><p>Add your header</p></footer>  
    <div id="container1" style="height: 200px; width:700px"></div>
    <div style="page-break-before:always;">
      <div id="container2" style="height: 200px;  width:700px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fiddle shows your two charts one on each page. Is that not what you asked for?

Comment: Yes, so it does. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I use IE9 for exporting highcharts to PDF, i use the like the one in the fiddle. The svg is getting rendered properly, but the chart is not generated, i get `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage` error. Can anyone please explain where am i going wrong?

Comment: I am one of the owners of the Cloudformatter site, we do not test anymore with IE 9.

Comment: using this wave after click on download for pdf i am redirect to other link like "https://export.highcharts.com/" this link so how can stop this redirection?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6eb7e/23/ isn't working. Can you please post a working sample? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the Highcharts you can setup your own exporitng server and export multiple charts to single PDF. See manual for that [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#export-multiple)

Using phantomJS you can break SVG to pages, like in related topic: [How to handle PDF pagination in PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043823/how-to-handle-pdf-pagination-in-phantomjs)

Comment: The JSfiddle I attached shows exactly that. It is the fiddle from the manual. What I am asking is whether or not it is possible to split the generate pdf into multiple pages, or whether there is a technique for doing so.

Comment: The link in related topic refers to breaking html into pages, not svg. It uses CSS attributes to break the divs in the document. I don't think it is possible to use these CSS attributes for breaking SVG. Be very happy to be shown otherwise!