# Highcharts multi-page PDF export

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, export

Right now highcharts only exports a 1 page PDF, I would like to add a page-break at the bottom of each page. This is what I have so far:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/z9zXM/1420/`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Highcharts export server does not support multi-page pdf - the ticket is open [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5834). One way to go is to set up your own server and handle creating pdf on your own. You can also split parts of the chart into seperate html elements and use a library which can handle creating multi-page pdf - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614717/export-multiple-highcharts-to-multi-page-pdf